# Rotating several images with different timings

Tags: javascript, image, image-rotation

I have three images side by side, left, middle and right. I want the first image on the left to change after 2 seconds, then the one in the middle to change 2 seconds later and then the one on the right to change 2 seconds after that. Then after another 2 seconds I want the first one on the left to change again and for the sequence to start all over again.

I've put together the javascript code for each image to have a certain start time and then a 6 second interval before changing again, this gives the effect I'm looking for.

The sequence works the first time round but when the first image is due to run through the sequence the second time round the whole thing seems to stick a bit and then all the images start changing together, as if they are all affecting one another. I don't know why this is since the code refers to each separately. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the code:

HTML Code:

```
<div>
<img id="mainImage" src="firstimage.jpg">
<img id="mainImage1" src="secondimage.jpg">
<img id="mainImage2" src="thirdimage.jpg">
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script>
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

var imageArray = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"];

var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage() {
  myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }
}

setTimeout(changeImage, 0000);
setInterval(changeImage,6000);
</script>

<script>
var myImage1 = document.getElementById("mainImage1");

var imageArray1 = ["image4.jpg","image5.jpg","image6.jpg"];

var imageIndex1 = 0;

function changeImage1() {
  myImage1.setAttribute("src",imageArray1[imageIndex1]);
  imageIndex1++;
  if (imageIndex1 >= imageArray1.length) {
    imageIndex1 = 0;
  }
}

setTimeout(changeImage1, 2000);
setInterval(changeImage1,6000);
</script>

<script>
var myImage2 = document.getElementById("mainImage2");

var imageArray2 = ["image7.jpg","image8.jpg","image9.jpg"];

var imageIndex2 = 0;

function changeImage2() {
  myImage2.setAttribute("src",imageArray2[imageIndex2]);
  imageIndex2++;
  if (imageIndex2 >= imageArray2.length) {
    imageIndex2 = 0;
  }
}

setTimeout(changeImage2, 4000);
setInterval(changeImage2,6000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

For each

```
setTimeout(changeImage2, x);
setInterval(changeImage2,6000);
```

change to

```
setTimeout(function() {
   setInterval(changeImage2,6000);
}, x);
```

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/bstd3fqu/4/

**Explanation:**

`setTimeout()` doesn't make runtime to sleep for certain time. It simply set a timer to execute the mentioned function after certain time. So all `setInterval()` calls are executing at almost same time in your implementation. I am just setting the interval in the `setTimeout` function so that these `setInterval()` calls are executing at different times.

Comment: That's great, many thanks. It works for the first 3 images but when I add another 5 below that in another div with increased times (
setTimeout(function() {
   setInterval(changeImage3,6000);
}, 6000);

setTimeout(function() {
   setInterval(changeImage4,6000);
}, 8000);

) etc, all those later images change together rather than in sequence. I'll have to look more closely, probably something simple I'm missing but I read that there's some issue with a maximum setting of 4000 in either setTimeout or setInterval, could it be some default setting that is causing this?

Comment: I've never heard about max setting 4000. Please try again, maybe you r missing something. One advice though, if you have multiple divs of same types, better store their informations in an array and loop the function over them instead of writing same code for every div.